# c# ZipFile CompressLevel not work

Tags: c#

I have some code for compressing a folder, it's working but the size of the archive is not different from the size of the folder. This is the code -

```
string startPath = "888";         //folder
string zipPath = "999.zip";       //archive
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath,CompressionLevel.Optimal,true);
```

What should I do to make the compression work as it supposed to?

Comment: what framework are you using?

Comment: I have a similar question. I suggest trying DotNetZip. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852405/compressing-pdf-file-makes-it-bigger

Comment: Your O/S (being very non-specific) can cause problems when interpreting the size of the output.  In some systems the files are allocated in segments of a fixed size, so a 1 byte file may occupy the same disk space as a 4kByte file if the segment size is 4kBytes.  Be careful to check the size of the output that's written to the file rather than the size of the file on the disk, or use data that is sufficiently large for the ZIP to compress it enough to save whole sectors.

Comment: Also be aware that different 'zip' (the standard one is a Lempel-Ziv) algorithms have an overhead which can be bigger than the source data for very small input sequences.  I don't know the details of the one you're using, but it may be one that is smart enough to know not to compress small sequences with very little redundancy.